# How to wait a request response and return the value?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-request

When I use a request module in node.js server, I have some problem such as wait and return.

I would like to receive a "responseObject" value at requestController.

To solve this problem, I have search the best way but I still do not find it.

How can solve this problem?

Thank in advance!! :)

=========================================================================

```
var requestToServer = require('request');

function getRequest(requestObject) {

    var urlInformation = requestObject['urlInformation'];
    var headerInformation = requestObject['headerInformation'];

    var jsonObject  = new Object( );

    // Creating the dynamic body set
    for(var i = 0; i < headerInformation.length; i++)
        jsonObject[headerInformation[i]['headerName']] = headerInformation[i]['headerValue'];

    requestToServer({
        url : urlInformation,
        method : 'GET',
        headers : jsonObject
    }, function(error, response ,body) {
        // todo response controlling
        var responseObject = response.headers;
        responseObject.body = body;
    });
}

// Controlling the submitted request
exports.requestController = function(requestObject) {
    var method = requestObject['methodInformation'];
    var resultObject = null;

    // Selecting the method
    if(method == "GET")
        resultObject = getRequest(requestObject);
    else if(method =="POST")
        resultObject = postRequest(requestObject);
    else if(method == "PUT")
        resultObject = putRequest(requestObject);
    else if(method == "DELETE")
        resultObject = deleteRequest(requestObject);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(resultObject));
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to use [fibers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fibers)

Comment: you can use callbacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `callbacks` in the following way.

```
function getRequest(requestObject, callback) {
    // some code
    requestToServer({
       url : urlInformation,
       method : 'GET',
       headers : jsonObject
    }, function(error, response ,body) {
       // todo response controlling
       var responseObject = response.headers;
       responseObject.body = body;
       callback(responseObject);
    }); 
}
```

And

```
// Controlling the submitted request
exports.requestController = function(requestObject) {
   var method = requestObject['methodInformation'];

   // Selecting the method
   if(method == "GET")
      getRequest(requestObject, function(resultObject){
          console.log(JSON.stringify(resultObject));
      });

   //some code
}
```

Hope, it helps.